# PyQt wait until page has loaded

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I want to save a page content to an image when it is fully loaded but sometimes i am getting output raster not rendered completely.

Code:

```
import sys
import signal
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
webpage = QWebPage()
def onLoadFinished(result):
    if not result:
        print "Request failed"
        sys.exit(1)
    webpage.setViewportSize(webpage.mainFrame().contentsSize())
    image = QImage(webpage.viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    webpage.mainFrame().render(painter)
    painter.end()
    if os.path.exists("output.png"):
        os.remove("output.png")
    image.save("output.png")
    sys.exit(0) # quit this application

webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl("file:///page.html"))
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), onLoadFinished)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Page is using JavaScript (onload function) to acquire google map (640x640px) .

Image: http://i56.tinypic.com/15ojg3s.png

Comment: related: [How to know when a web page is loaded when using QtWebKit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302874/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this even possible. For a static website this could probably work, but Google Maps will load tiles dynamically, and I'm in doubt it will emit a usuable "I'm done" signal.

But it seems you only want an image of a Google map? Have you looked at their API? They allow you to [generate static maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), just by building a URL.

Example

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap &markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318 &markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

[image: Example map]

Comment: Unfortunately static maps is not suitable for what I'm trying to achieve - I've tried that. Probably I'll try with this: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/layerLoadMonitoring.html . Thank's for help anyway