# How to Quit Qapplication (PyQt) with python or Shell code

Tags: python, pyqt

Hi Everybody i'm newbie in almost every technology that i'm about to talk you about below , 
i'm launching an `QApplication` with `sys.exit(qapp.exec_())` (required because i'm using a `QWebView` in my python class) and everything's fine with that except that the application does not quit by its own after execution and this is causing a problem when i call this Qapplication through a REST Django webservice  (the server won't quit loading) , so i was wondering if  there's any solution for that , thank you ,
I was thinking of performing a SIGTSTP (ctrl + z) with python after launching the app , is this a practical solution?

Here is a portion of the code

```
def main():
    import sys
    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myappWebView = myappWebView()
    myappWebView.load('http://website.com')
    myappWebView.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A window is being launched whenever i execute this and the linux console won't prompt me for a new command and is stuck until i close the window manually .

Comment: How do you decide that work is done?

Comment: In the load method i fill in some files with some retrieved code , so right after the execution i want the application to stop and quit

Comment: Can you add `QCoreApplication.exit()` to the end of the load method?

Comment: I cannot because the QApplication (or the QCoreApplication) is being instanciated in the main() function

Comment: It's static method, you don't need to write `qApp.exit()`, just write `QApplication.exit()`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer without seeing code, but I think you can call [`QCoreApplication.exit()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#exit) when job is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can quit the application when the page has finished loading:

```
myappWebView.loadFinished.connect(qApp.quit)
```

Or if the page has some javascript that needs time to execute, you can use a timer to delay the application closing:

```
timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(2000) # 2 seconds
myappWebView.loadFinished.connect(timer.start)
timer.timeout.connect(qApp.quit)
```

(Or you can choose a more complicated and maybe more accurate method: [How to know when a web page is loaded when using QtWebKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302874/how-to-know-when-a-web-page-is-loaded-when-using-qtwebkit) ).